# Kubernetes pod doesn't accept connections on exposed port

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have a multi container pod deployment that exposes port 8080 the port inside the container is accessible through localhost but not the pod IP 
when I telnet on the pod local host I'm able to connect but when I telnet on the pod IP that's in /etc/hosts I get connection refused.

deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: test
 namespace: yara
 labels:
   component: test-multi-container-pod
  spec:
 replicas: 1
 template:
   metadata:
     labels:
       app: test
          spec:
     serviceAccountName: test
     containers:
       - name: container-1
         image: "gcr.io/projectID/my-image1:v1.9.3"
         pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
         resources:
           limits:
             cpu: 1000m
             memory: 2Gi
            requests:
             cpu: 500m
             memory: 2Gi             
       - name: container2
         image: "gcr.io/projectID/my-image2:0.0.107"
          pullPolicy: "IfNotPresent"
          securityContext:
           runAsUser: 0
         resources:
           limits:
             cpu: 1000m
             memory: 2Gi
           requests:
             cpu: 500m
             memory: 2Gi   
       - name:  "app-container"
       ## nodejs image that exposes ports 3000 & 8080
         image: "gcr.io/projectID/node:8.9.4_1804082101"
         workingDir: "/usr/src/app"
         pullPolicy: "Always"
         command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
         ports:
         - name: http
           containerPort: 3000
         - name: graphql
           containerPort: 8080
         resources:
           limits:
             cpu: 1500m
             memory: 2Gi
           requests:
             cpu: 1500m
             memory: 2Gi
```

service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: test-app
  namespace: "yara"
  labels:
    component: test-multi-container-pod
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: http
    port: 3000
    targetPort: http
  - protocol: TCP
    name: graphql
    port: 8080
    targetPort: graphql
  selector:
    component: test-multi-container-pod
```

Answer (score 1):

The `command` option in Pod Spec overrides `Entrypoint` option in Docker Container, that's why you actually run tail instead of your application

```
  - name: "app-container" 
    ...
    command: ["tail", "-f", "/dev/null"]
```

According to the [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-command-argument-container/), `command` in kubernetes overrides docker containers `entrypoint` with the following rules:

- If you do not supply command or args for a Container, the defaults defined in the Docker image are used.
- If you supply a command but no args for a Container, only the supplied command is used. The default EntryPoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored.
- If you supply only args for a Container, the default Entrypoint defined in the Docker image is run with the args that you supplied.
- If you supply a command and args, the default Entrypoint and the default Cmd defined in the Docker image are ignored. Your command is run with your args.

All containers in a Pod share the same network namespace. It looks similar, as if processes from containers in the Pod would run on the same host and be able to bind only to ports which aren't occupied by other processes in the same Pod. Practically, if you configure two containers that use the same port binding, one of them fails to start with error: "[emerg] 1#1: bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)".

If you need that particular pod container process to be found and accessed by other Pods and Services, you can describe it with `port:` directive in [Pod Spec](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.10/#container-v1-core). It gives the system additional information about the network connections a container uses, but is primarily informational. ***Not specifying a port in Pod Spec does not  prevent that port from being exposed.*** Any port which is listening on the default "0.0.0.0" address inside a container will be accessible from the network by the Pod address and from other containers in the pod via `localhost`.

So, the response you've received from localhost:8080 could be delivered from another container in the pod which binds to that port.

You can find a good explanation of the Pod networking in this [article](https://medium.com/google-cloud/understanding-kubernetes-networking-pods-7117dd28727).

Comment: so even if the service point to the container port, it won't work because of `entrypoint` runs tail command?

Comment: Yes, you need to start application process for that, not only tail.

Comment: what if we want the pod to start with `tail` command and later we connect inside the pod to start an application on 8080port and expose that to service and ingress? As you telling this won't work in kuberentes env, if so what would be a solution if we want to start an application manually like said before but still expose the port to external IP via ingress.

Comment: The main benefit of kubernetes, that you don’t need to do process management manually. To collect logs there are several convenient ways, just google for it or ask new question on stackoverflow.